# Challenges with caesar-cipher: Encoding and Decoding code

Tags: java, netbeans, caesar-cipher

I am new to Java and this is what I have to do:
  Write a program that lets the user input a message and a shift value and then outputs the encoded message
Write a separate program that lets the user input a coded message using the first program and then decodes it for you and you cannot use StringBuffer or StringBuilder

What I am trying to do here is make the second part of the program but I am having some problems. When you add shift value, it only encodes it by 1 no matter what number you input and when I try to decode, it gives me an error.

```
public class part2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text;
        String key;
        int shift;

        System.out.println("Enter message:");
        text = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter encryption key:");
        key = sc.next();
        shift = key.length(); {
            System.out.println("1.Encrypt\n2.Decrypt\n3.Exit...");
            int choice = sc.nextInt();
            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Encryptedmessage..." + encrypt(text, shift));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //send retrived string from encrypt() method and keyLength to decrypt() method it returns 'Decrypted' string
                    System.out.println("Decrypted message..." + decrypt(encrypt(text, shift), shift));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //exit from the program
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid option..");
            }
        }
    }
    public static String encrypt(String text, int shift) {

        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            char letter = text.charAt(i);

            // shift only letters (leave other characters alone)
            if (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z') {
                letter = (char)(letter + shift);

                // may need to wrap around
                if (letter > 'z') {
                    letter = (char)(letter - 26);
                } else if (letter < 'a') {
                    letter = (char)(letter + 26);
                }
            }
            System.out.print(letter);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String str, int keyLength) {
        String decrypted = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {

            int c = str.charAt(i);

            if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                c = c - (keyLength % 26);
                if (c < 'A')
                    c = c + 26;
            } else if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                c = c - (keyLength % 26);
                if (c < 'a')
                    c = c + 26;
            }
            decrypted = decrypted + (char) c;
        }
        return decrypted;
    }
}
```

This is my code for the first part:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type a message you want to be coded: ");
        String message = console.nextLine();
        message = message.toLowerCase();

        System.out.print("Enter a Shift: ");
        int key = console.nextInt();
    if (key < 1 || key > 25) {
                System.out.printf(" The key must be between 1 and 25, you entered %d.\n", key);
            }
        while (key < 1 || key > 25);

        encode(message, key);
    }

    // This method encodes the given text string using a Caesar
    // cipher, shifting each letter by the given number of places.
    public static void encode(String text, int shift) {
        System.out.print("The encoded message: \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            char letter = text.charAt(i);

            // shift only letters (leave other characters alone)
            if (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z') {
                letter = (char) (letter + shift);

                // may need to wrap around
                if (letter > 'z') {
                    letter = (char) (letter - 26);
                } else if (letter < 'a') {
                    letter = (char) (letter + 26);
                }
            }
            System.out.print(letter);
        }
    }
```

This is the code for first part and it works perfectly. Just need help with the second part

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems here.

First, you are not quite done with the first part, like you think. Let's look at your `encrypt` method:

```
public static String encrypt(String text, int shift) {

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char letter = text.charAt(i);

        // shift only letters (leave other characters alone)
        if (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z') {
            letter = (char)(letter + shift);

            // may need to wrap around
            if (letter > 'z') {
                letter = (char)(letter - 26);
            } else if (letter < 'a') {
                letter = (char)(letter + 26);
            }
        }
        System.out.print(letter); // <- This is part of your problem
    }
    return null; // <- This is part of your problem
}
```

When we call this, we output the encoded string to the console, but look at the last line: we return `null`. You need to figure out a way to store the encoded message and then return it. Otherwise, you will always get a `NullPointerException` on this line in your `main` method:

```
System.out.println("Decrypted message..." + decrypt(encrypt(text, shift), shift));
```

The second problem is that you may be misunderstanding your assignment. Looking at that line above, once you have `encrypt` working, you still have a useless `decrypt` option: it will always give you back the message you enter. What I *think* you want to be doing is to just `decrypt` the message, with the user passing in an already encrypted message. But, that's just my hunch, and you might want to check with your instructor on that.

Comment: @Jay - Okay, I see you added your code from part1. You are correct, that looks fine. What I am getting at is that your encoding `encrypt` in this second part is not quite right. Look at the lines I called out in my answer. You can fix this by adding one line at the top of `encrypt`, and then changing those two line I commented on. You need to return the encoded message, not just print it.

Comment: I tried fixing it but if I remove the return statement it gives me an error and in your comment you wrote that I can fix this by adding one line. What do you mean by that? Thanks for your help

Comment: @Jay - I'm really trying to help you understand the issue here without just doing your homework for you. Let's look at the method. The signature is `public static String encrypt(String text, int shift)`. The third word, `String` means you need to `return` a `String`. In this case, the `String` should be the encrypted message. Right now, you are only returning `null`. Instead of just printing to the console, you need to store that message to a `String` variable and `return` that. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh ok now I see what you mean. Thank you for your help!